# Rest client post request works in postman but not in c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq;
using System.Web; 
using System.Web.UI; 
using System.Web.UI.WebControls; 
using RestSharp; 
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace mobile_link_account 
{
    public partial class update_mobile_link_ngb : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            var client = new RestClient("https://xyz.apcz.in/appkvvcl/ngb/backend/api/v1/authentication/login");
           

            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "e8a9e567-f7e6-4820-9096-a0aef2c2b003");
            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
          
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            request.AddParameter("undefined", "{\n    \"username\": \"xyz\",\n    \"password\": \"xys\"\n}",
ParameterType.RequestBody);

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            for (int i = 0; i < response.Headers.Count; i++)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("***************" + response.Headers[i]);
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("" + response.StatusCode);
        }
    }
}
```

> Ouput Headers:
>
> ***************x-content-type-options=nosniff
> ***************x-xss-protection=1; mode=block
> ***************pragma=no-cache
> ***************x-frame-options=DENY
> ***************Vary=accept-encoding
> ***************content-encoding=
> ***************transfer-encoding=chunked
> ***************connection=close
> ***************Cache-Control=no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
> ***************Content-Type=application/json;charset=UTF-8
> ***************Date=Tue, 26 Oct 2021 11:17:38 GMT
> ***************Expires=0
> ***************X-Powered-By=Express InternalServerError

Comment: Yes ..... and !?!? What happens? Do you get an error - if so : ***what*** error?? Please post some more context and information about your situation - as is, no one will be able to help you!

Comment: I am getting error message "Internal Server error"  but post method working fine when tested on postman

Answer (score 1):

if it is an internal server error i.e. 500 then debug that method with a breakpoint and tell us what happens